# Using #pragma for PIC pins

Tags: c, pic, pragma, pins

Is it possible to use `#pragma` to set `TRIS` registers to 1/0 and `PORT` registers to ON/OFF?
I understand this question may sound overly-simplistic, however, I'm eager for confirmation.

Comment: Like use #pragma to force the output binary to write the binary directly to the registers and setup everything. Not sure if it is possible but even if you could you shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

The `#pragma` directive is the method specified by the C standard for providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is conveyed in the language itself.
If you want to set/reset a port register you had to do it during the runtime of program. something like:

```
TRISA = 0x00;
```

So the simple answer is:No, you can't

Comment: The error with that is that each time I try to write some form of TRIS command in the space of the program, it simply doesn't recognize it, and I'm always given the error "Declaration of Identifier cannot be found".

Comment: Have you include `xc.h`? I think It's time for a new question with sourcecode and the detailed error message.

Comment: Yes, I have included <xc.h> after my pragmas. I keep getting the error "Unresolved inside include file".

Comment: `#include xc.h`should be the first line. Maybe show code in a new question